# How to compare fixed order of items on column per user?

Tags: python, compare, sequence, rank

I wanted to see how many users pick what items in what order. I want to be able to tell how many users have the same picking orders.

This is what my data looks like:

```
User        Items        Order
1           Banana       1
            Apple        2
            Peach        3

2           Banana       1
            Peach        2
            Apple        3
            Orange       4

3           Banana       1
            Apple        2
            Peach        3

4           Banana       1
            Apple        2
            Peach        3
            Orange       4
```

Does anybody have any tips on how to compare the order of these items to each other? Especially in a much bigger set?

Answer (score 0):

A beginning of answer:

```
user1 = {"item1": "Orange", "item2": "Apple", "item3": "banane"}
user2 = {"item1": "Orange", "item2": "Apple", "item3": "banane"}
user3 = {"item1": "Orange", "item2": "Apple", "item3": "banane", "item4": "Peach"}

print(user1 == user2)
print(user1 == user3)
```

The first print return True and the second return False.

Hope that help ...